# Is the biconjugate of a continuous functions also continuous?

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be given and assume that $|f(x)|\leq C|x|^2$. Is it true that the bi-(convex/Fenchel)-conjugate $f^{**}$ is also continuous.

It was claimed in a book without a proof. Of course I checked the related Fenchel relations but these only provide a semicontinuity result for the (bi)conjugate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{**}\le f$ and $f$ is bounded above on an open set makes $f^{**}$ bounded above on an open set so because $f^{**}$ is convex lower semicontinuous it is continuous on the interior of its domain.

Comment: The transition from convex lower semicontinuous to continuous is the generalization of the 1-D  result to N-D that convex functions are continuous on their domain? Is the boundedness from above needed to obtain a proper convex function $f**$?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 The answer to both questions is negative. Convex functions are continuous on the interior of their domain if they are bounded above on an open subset of their domain (that holds in any space). Boundedness from above has nothing to do with proving that the function is proper because it can be identically $-\infty$.

Comment: in my case, the function $f$ is not identically $\infty$, thus $f^{**}\leq f$ is proper. Thought, you where using this assumption. Could you provide a reference for the continuity result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I was talking about $f^{**}$ which can be identically $-\infty$. You still have to show that $f^{**}$ is proper. Convex Analysis by R.T. Rockafellar Theorem 10.1 p.82 has the finite dimensional case.